# Styling a p element

Tags: html, css

For some reason I cannot get the styling for my

```
nav-content-right-notif-num p
```

div to apply. I would like the number "4" (or any text) to be centered in the

```
nav-content-right-notif-num
```

div (the red circle). But the `<p>` just inherits a different styling. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my source:

http://jsfiddle.net/n4sXe/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `p` is floating left.  Because it's floating, it's no-longer occupying the full width of the `div`. The text *is* centered, but it's centered within the narrowed `p`.

Perhaps you don't need to make the `p` float.

Comment: Inspect it using your choice of browser developer tools and you'll see that some of the CSS styles cause it to float. You may have to add a `float: none` to bypass inherited styles.